# iOS SDK Detect if app was updated or a new install

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sdk, updates

After looking at a bunch of SO posts about detecting if this is a fresh install or not, I'm assuming what I want to do is impossible, but I'm going to ask just in case there's a trick I'm unsure of.

I am building an SDK to be integrated into apps, and I want to be able to tell when the SDK gets initialized for the **very first time** if it's from a brand new install, or from an app update which included our SDK.

I could have the integrator to call something like `[MySDK initializeIsNewInstall:YES/NO]` and force them to figure out which it is (using NSDefaults or whatever), but I'd rather be able to figure it out automatically somehow.

If anyone has any ideas, that would be great.

Comment: Store the version identifier of your app on each launch in the userdefaults. Before that check if the version identifier is present - no: new install; yes - differs from the current one: update; same one - regular launch. Pretty straight forward.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding you, that would not solve my problem. I want to know if the very first time the SDK gets called if it's being called from a new installation or if it's being called from an existing installation that got updated to include the SDK.

Comment: That easily solves that problem. Just make your SDK check for the identifier on first call: present? - yes: previously used; no: new install.

Comment: I don't think so. Imagine an app on my phone that the developer updates to include the SDK.  First time the app launches and calls my SDK, there's no identifier there. Same as if it was a new install.

Comment: I can check with my SDK if the app version got updated after the SDK got added, but can't tell the very first time the SDK is called if it's a new install or update.

Comment: Ahh, you want to differentiate between first launch all together and new version with the SDK added in - no, probably not possible with your SDK alone.

Comment: That's what I'm assuming. Hoping I'm wrong.

Comment: You can't just use NSUserDefaults since app could be removed/re-installed,  data not persists, you need some unique value (like a device_id, unfortunately it's deprecated and IDFA is also not unique) to store somewhere in cloud or external source

Comment: @Injectios I don't care if it's from a removed/re-installed scenario, but I want to differentiate between a clean install with the SDK and an update of the app which didn't have the SDK before and now does.

It's too bad Apple doesn't pass this type of info into the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

Comment: I'm afraid it's impossible to differentiate a VERY first install, hope I'm wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest pretty good trick by using `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`

do it like this,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isApplicationUpdated"]){
// application was updated//
// make another userDefaults to store version number and confirm if it is updated here.
}
else{
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBookForKey:@"isApplicationUpdated"]
// as for the first time application would not find this key and you can use it after you have updated the app do stuff here
}
```

Comment: That would not solve my problem. I want to know if the first time the SDK gets called if it's being called from a new installation or if it's being called from an existing installation that got updated.

Comment: are you talking about iOS SDK?

Comment: I am building an iOS framework that will get included into other apps.

Comment: This is something i have never done before, I am sorry

Answer (score 0):

Afaik the only way to detect whether your app was updated or freshly installed in your case is to check your persistence for something that should be there from a **previous** version. For future checks you can add your own flag to your persistence.